# Why is my very simple ElasticSearch query failing, SearchPhaseExecutionException

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to do a search for "dog chew" in the invention-title field in my PatentGrants type. 
query url: POST http://localhost:9200/patents/patentGrants/_search 
query body:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {
      "invention-title": "dog chew"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is a picture of the data in my patents index and below that is a picture of my query and the error message.
[image: Picture of the information in my patents index]

[image: My query and resulting exception message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "inventionTitle": "dog chew"
    }
  }
}
```

1. The field name in the screenshot is `inventionTitle` not `invention-title`.
2. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-match-all-query.html - use `match` instead of `match_all`. `match_all` doesn't accept a search query.